# React Router not rendering my children elements inside my layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

app.js

```
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

// Components
import Home from './components/Home';
import Layout from './Layout';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Layout>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          </Routes>
        </Layout>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default App;
```

layout

```
import React from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

//components
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Navbar />
      <Outlet />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

Here the `Home` page that I want to show as children content inside the layout.

```
import React from 'react'
import Movies from './MoviesComponent'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>hello</>
  )
}

export default Home
```

I want to render the child components inside the layout. I have had trouble trying for a while, I was able to do it in an older version of `react-router` but in v6, things changed so much. I am trying to do the same but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, `Outlet` is used when you have nested `Route`.
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet

That's not the case for your `Layout`. Try using `children`:

```
import React from 'react';

//components
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Navbar/>
            {children}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

Comment: yeap i did that before, but i research about my issue and its that i was using wrong the component in the element property of the route, it has to be "<Home/>" instead of "Home", but thanks for your time mate.

Answer (score 1):

please use

```
       import { createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    
        const router=createBrowserRouter([
          {
            path:'/',
            element:<Home/>
          },
          {
            path:'/Test',
            element:<Test payload={payload}/>
          }
        ]);
        
        root.render(
        <Layout router={router}>
     </Layout>
);
```

And inside Layout Component

```
import { Fragment } from "react"
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

const Layout=({router})=>{
    return(<Fragment>
        <RouterProvider router={router}>
 </RouterProvider>
    </Fragment>)
}

Layout.displayName='Layout';

export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

You've at least a couple of issues:

1. The `Layout` component isn't rendered as a [Layout Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes), so it rendering an `Outlet` is moot since there it's not wrapping children `Route` component to render their content into the outlet.
2. The `Home` component is incorrectly rendered by the `Route`. The RRDv6 `Route` component API changed from v5 and there is no longer any `component` prop. All the rendering props were replaced by a single `element` prop taking a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX, prop value.

## Solution

Render `Layout` as a layout route and correctly render the home route.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<Layout />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Box>
  );
}
```